client component inside server component
I am trying Nextjs app rounter, when client component inside of server component some warning showing.
import Client from "@/component/client";

export default async function Home() {
    return (
        <section>
            <h1 className="text-center text-gray-900">I am server</h1>
            <Client />
        </section>
    );
}

'use client'

export default async function Client() {
    return (
        <div className="mt-8 flex justify-center">
            <button
                onClick={() => console.log("hello")}
                className="bg-blue-700 py-2 px-4 font-semibold rounded-md hover:bg-blue-900"
            >
                I am clients
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

showing warning error
enter image description here
search nextjs docs ?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

This question is similar to: Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components in next.js. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
